# Push Array values with a dynamic keyname in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using a function to push values to an array with two parameters.In this the second parameter indicates the level of arrays.so i need to push values to that array using this `level` params value.

Here is my code:

```
addLevel1(i, level) {
        let advArr1                                 =   {};
        let nextLevel                               =   parseInt(level)+1
        advArr1["level"+level+"_adv_url"]           =   "";
        advArr1["level"+level+"_custom_variables"]  =   "";
        advArr1["level"+level+"_percentage"]        =   "";
        advArr1["level"+level+"_status"]            =   "";
        advArr1["level"+nextLevel]                  =   [];
        this.containers[i].level1.push(advArr1);
        console.log(this.containers);
};
```

In this instread of

```
this.containers[i].level1.push(advArr1);
```

I need dynamic vale for level1. i.e. if param level is 1 it should be

```
this.containers[i].level1.push(advArr1);
```

and if param level is 2 it will be

```
this.containers[i].level2.push(advArr1);
```

Comment: Use the same syntax you already used above.

Comment: Use array bracket notation instead of property notation.

Comment: You should probably make a nested array of objects instead of keys like that.

Comment: do you have some data to have a look to the wanted structure?

Answer (score 1):

The sense of objects is that you can easily look up properties *by name*. As you mix in the dynamic level variable into it, you defeat that purpose:

```
  const levels = [
   { level1_status: "ok" },
   { level2_status: "wrong" }
 ];

 for(const level of levels) {
   // How to get the status here?
   level["level" + /*How to get the level?*/ "_status"]
 }
```

Now instead, you should have *static* keys, so all levels should have the same keys. To differentiate different levels, you could use a *level property*:

```
  const levels = [
   { level: 1, status: "ok" },
   { level: 2, status: "wrong" }
  ];

  for(const level of levels) {
    console.log("Level:", level.level); // isn't that simple?

    console.log("has Status:", level.status); // Wohoo!
  }
```

Now the next thing is that `containers[i].level1` thing: If you would have a `levels` array property on the container, you could just access it as `containers[i].levels[1]` without any problems. The main benefit is, that you can now go easily over the different levels of a container: `for(const level of container.levels)`.

Under the assumption that the container has such an array, your code could be:

```
 addLevel(i, level){
    this.containers[i].levels[level] = {
      level,
      nextLevel: level + 1,
      advUrl: "",
      percentage: 0, // does make more sense than a string, right?
       status: "",
   };
 }

 // somewhere:
 context.addLevel(/*i*/ 0, /*level*/ 1);
```

Comment: i am getting  ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [brackets to access object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of using dot notation:

```
this.containers[i][level].push(advArr1);
```

Comment: ExperimentV4Component.html:184 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Sounds like `this.containers[i]` does not have a `level1` property. What does `console.log(this.containers[i])` show?